# How to trigger regular snapshot of azure file share

Tags: azure-storage

**Daily snapshot triggering for Azure storage file share**

> I would like to trigger azure file share snapshot on daily basis
>   without any manual effort, Can I enable It somewhere via azure portal
>   or via azure CLI ?

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution as 
Create a bash script and execute It via cronjob from a Linux server via azure CLI. The [azure wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-azure-cli) lists the required commands

**To create the share snapshot**

```
az storage share snapshot -n <share name>
```

**To delete the snapshot**

```
az storage share delete -n <share name> --snapshot '2017-10-04T23:28:35.0000000Z'
```